# How to close a collapse with a button

Tags: jquery, css

How do you collapse a collapse with a button?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contents" type="button">
            Collase stuff
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="contents">
            Some content
        </div>
        <button id="cls">CLose</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

i also tried it with javascript

```
$(document).click(function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('#cls')){
            $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        }
    });
```

Comment: And `.collapse()` is what? What library are you using?

Comment: It seems you are using bootstrap.. please add a code snippet to help us assist you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the condition if e.target is not equal to the close button then execute, which is not correct. So just remove "!" from the if condition.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('#cls')){
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
});
```